# fnRedraw & fnReloadAjax will not refresh datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I have been working on getting a table to reload with new data based on the ajax url.

I get the table to load correctly the first time but i can not get it to refresh.

```
$(function() {
    var datepicker = $( "#date-picker" );
    var table = $("#reports1").dataTable({
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
        bJQueryUI: true,
        ajax: "http://" + window.location.host + "/admin/update_reports/" + datepicker.val(),
        bProcessing: true,
        columns: [
            {
                sTitle: "User",
                data: "user_email"
            },
             ...
            {
                sTitle: "Not Interested",
                data: "notinterested"
            }
        ]
    });
    datepicker.datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    }).attr('readonly','readonly').css("background","white").on('change', function(){
        alert("Date changed to " + datepicker.val());
        table.ajax.reload();
    });
});
```

I do get the Alert so i know it gets that far

I tried this  `alert( 'Data source: ' + table.ajax.url() );`

and get this error `TypeError: table.ajax is undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the FIX:**

```
var source = "http://" + window.location.host + "/admin/update_reports/" + datepicker.val()
table.api().ajax.url(source).load();
```

Comment: The correct way to do it is simply: `table.fnDraw()`

Comment: fnDraw() does not update the Ajax URL. and it would have to be table.api().fnDraw unless i changed the dataTable to DataTable

Comment: True, you'd have to use `fnServerParams` to pass the date value instead.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps in second time changed `datepicker.val()`

and `ajax: "http://" + window.location.host + "/admin/update_reports/" + datepicker.val(),`

does not exist!

Comment: Shouldnt it pull the new date every time it is called